DNSSEC and subdomains on Azure DNS
Situation:

domain.com is registered with provider X
sub.domain.com is registered in Azure

We have added NS records for sub.domain.com which point to the correct Azure DNS servers.
Resolution of host.sub.domain.com works as intended. When we were at provider Y, we had DNSSEC enabled on the main domain.com and everything worked fine.
Now we want to activate DNSSEC on the main domain at provider X. Once enabled, the sub.domain.com resources result in a Server Failure, as far as I can deduce because Azure DNS doesn't have DNSSEC (it's 'it's on the roadmap' since at least 2019 and no ETA is known, as far as I know).
Is there a way to enable DNSSEC on the main domain, but exclude the sub.domain.com zone?
The following info is when DNSSEC was enabled and the error occurred:
The error that Google DNS gave when querying host.sub.domain.com is:
{
  ....
  "Comment": "Resolution failure. Please check https://intodns.com/host.sub.domain.com",
  "extended_dns_errors": [
    {
      "info_code": 22,
      "extra_text": "At delegation domain.com for sub.domain.com/ds"
    }
  ]
  ....
}

But recursive DNS worked fine:
dig +trace host.sub.domain.com @8.8.8.8
 
; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> +trace host.sub.domain.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
.                       87203   IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       87203   IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20240228050000 20240215040000 30903 . eiIbJzFD74pJwP/o0r1Z91AhBFQfEYaO6rOOCaQIH4Vo/zwF+grKyPEa wi2eiU8GEEdZOsfbCNkQIch8+0ue2fABl7qeMH196uNAWVaxL2QDRr2I untt6fq3xLhfWT8EYOfEDTG3wdnu/udVq9R4IjKn73juDcqP0g3gSDAr psZe3sQIcG3u9pgiVQrPjy0Ibxd2G2vbobjHIRBbrx7ZYQkbFGGSTaM1 QDHMYR91Uj2+RvtZPbVz19K0D5W2J6kBkN7Dq+ANIE9qKHYheRybv+p3 Df0HOqhNlkjGNXTUCicOUql+xbpgOVk+RqA3b7kxC2jqQC+ZK1e2OvSD FXcvCw==
;; Received 525 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) in 40 ms
 
nl.                     172800  IN      NS      ns1.dns.nl.
nl.                     172800  IN      NS      ns3.dns.nl.
nl.                     172800  IN      NS      ns4.dns.nl.
nl.                     86400   IN      DS      17153 13 2 C5DFDDC91E7532562A35F3C2CD30823894BE08F20101F1ABF45C8AB9 739F3F49
nl.                     86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20240228050000 20240215040000 30903 . iHVs9zBiHfjJy2IUtacqyo3bY6cn9ammq1QusJXj9ykT19XIzu5hYqLl /snI1LbTwhIyJZyfft3cAm3YiBS+3IXZCSoFem89OdeKH7dRQtrPk5vW Cn1a5Id16XrUemi0zhpf+OVMa/IqAOTvz1ZVG6ShQ2jz94SSyBxb1rjf sqdviL7Pua0L7oEixtz0tbqVjIfhh5gHSSmWe04D9X3ZLGHM2kPDqKDG +wIcemN9QfejeFBEXKWlr8aSH9jLnSbpxq4rR8kMDjNpPQ38MDKQzM3/ q6tvdPQKuSkSwBes45K7/g2GlJh8sqIhDZC7QOaErAJo70CjdZtN9O53 cXsHoA==
;; Received 607 bytes from 192.36.148.17#53(i.root-servers.net) in 229 ms
 
domain.com.              3600    IN      NS      ns4.sectigoweb.com.
domain.com.              3600    IN      NS      ns1.sectigoweb.com.
domain.com.              3600    IN      NS      ns2.sectigoweb.com.
domain.com.              3600    IN      NS      ns3.sectigoweb.com.
domain.com.              3600    IN      DS      10559 8 2 13E775DCB89F3146F2CCB2B2C3F6D0739C22937A555BDFE8D8713880 1A495E79
domain.com.              3600    IN      RRSIG   DS 13 2 3600 20240228150444 20240214120731 15365 nl. 6poz7TNNCk7WIkc8J/lCZr9GkFuF/vLaXO6oOY98vShefKePCGlEe4mh cOQykjJVMWiAPJTWAPOjtrgxE6Hg8A==
;; Received 291 bytes from 194.0.25.24#53(ns3.dns.nl) in 30 ms
 
sub.domain.com.           600     IN      NS      ns1-09.azure-dns.com.
sub.domain.com.           600     IN      NS      ns2-09.azure-dns.net.
sub.domain.com.           600     IN      NS      ns3-09.azure-dns.org.
sub.domain.com.           600     IN      NS      ns4-09.azure-dns.info.
host.sub.domain.com.  300     IN      NSEC    \000.host.sub.domain.com. NS RRSIG NSEC
domain.com.              300     IN      RRSIG   SOA 8 2 3600 20240514134541 20240214134541 23593 domain.com. JgbTRDbxJ6Jmylr64SU7/9ga1mC0w3ajf7E98rr0V8UI2/fLOAXDje/5 oCJwqpiIy8tAwi8IyB7EQQKQdYRBkyhXGcDQpDTz+JkWwxvILV4zZpa8 j8dxote+P5s4k2FO4wercV5zYxPPyiJ/b865UI83Z0P9M5qmwcvtVl/2 /Tw=
host.sub.domain.com.  300     IN      RRSIG   NSEC 8 5 300 20240514134541 20240214134541 23593 domain.com. qh4EhKb5gGcmqiLlaXEUx0YLWeXiYDsPLEz6osxCPCE0XmDF/wv1lth5 68UWG5/mymglhF/l07GggnRJdgJS0CRNtvN5zLScS1kCRYbCF2YJC8wE LOL/3aJVeupocfsWeLnG+KFsukwTSx8sxgxmiwO/KOAX0NnbOvzux3Jn s5Y=
;; Received 570 bytes from 162.159.27.4#53(ns4.sectigoweb.com) in 40 ms
 
host.sub.domain.com.  3600    IN      A       40.50.60.70
;; Received 66 bytes from 204.14.183.7#53(ns3-09.azure-dns.org) in 30 ms

Joost

That's an unexpected Server Failure, actually – as far as I know, it is supposed to work by default. Can you get a dnsviz.net scan of the domain while it's broken like that?

I can't enable it as it would make several production systems unavailable. I've added the error and a DNS trace to the original text


Is there a way to enable DNSSEC on the main domain, but exclude the sub.domain.com zone?

That's already the default behavior. DNSSEC is not enabled per-domain – it is enabled per-delegation, with DS records "enabling" it when they are added alongside the delegation NS records. If there's a DS record, the child zone has to be signed using a matching key; if there are no DS records, the child zone can remain unsigned.
It's completely valid to have a delegation from a signed domain to an unsigned child domain, as resolvers can use NSEC to get a signed proof of absence of the DS records (i.e. there is no risk for downgrade attack). In fact, that's how your domain.com currently works – it's an unsigned zone delegated from a signed TLD zone.
(Though you said that you cannot enable DNSSEC, but your 'dig' output says that the delegation at domain.com is DNSSEC-enabled, because the parent zone has DS records for it – so there's something that doesn't match up.)

The dig response was when DNSSEC was enabled: A recursive query worked fine, a direct query resulted in a failure with error 22.
And with 'can't enable' I meant 'I am not allowed to enable until I am really sure that the problem won't return', not 'I am technically unable to enable DNSSEC'.
Currently DNSSEC is turned off for the domain.
